# Is possible to Cache a Mysql View?

Tags: mysql

I'have a mysql view that is taking a bit too long, I know i can set a cache globally with mysql but I want to cache only one specific view  is that possible ?

Comment: Short answer: no. That'd be a materialised view, which MySQL [does not support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-views.html#faq-mysql-have-materialized-views). You could have also benefited from query cache, but that was [deprecated and removed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html).

Comment: A former coworker of mine implemented materialized views for MySQL: https://github.com/greenlion/swanhart-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cache a view but you can create a table that would save that record permanently.

You will be able to access the same dataset without waiting for the execution of the conditions of the view.

```
CREATE TABLE my_view_cache as SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

Comment: I understand thank you